# Fixing CA1810: Initialize reference type static fields inline

Tags: c#

I have this tiny static class. I need to initialize this jagged array and i'll have to do some more stuff later.

```
namespace Kerumaton
{
  static internal class WorldGrid
  {
    static public int gridWidth;
    static public int gridHeight;
    static public int gridSizeX, gridSizeY;
    static public int[][] gridArray;

    static WorldGrid()
    {
        gridWidth = 10;
        gridHeight = 10;
        gridSizeX = World.imageWidth % gridWidth;
        gridSizeY = World.imageHeight % gridHeight;
        gridArray = new int[gridSizeX][];
        for (int i = 0; i < gridArray.Length; i++)
        {
            gridArray[i] = new int[gridSizeY];
        }
    }
  }
}
```

But i get a warning telling me that it would be a good idea to remove the static constructor and initialize the variable where they are declared.

Sure, yes please, i hear this have significant performance impact.

But how ? Is there a way to run code when declaring a variable ? Am i misunderstanding something ? is the warning a false alarm ? I'm sure the answer is obvious but my google-fu only show me very simple exemple like dictionary inline initialization.

I'm using C# 8, Core 3.x, VS2019

Comment: Why do you need to split fields declaration and their assignment?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to fix "CA1810: Initialize reference type static fields inline" with an abstract base...?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5090076/how-to-fix-ca1810-initialize-reference-type-static-fields-inline-with-an-abst)

Comment: For reference you can initialize it inline pretty easily. It isnt super pretty but `new int[5].Select(_ => new int[3]).ToArray()` works.

Comment: @Pavel no, i've read it already and don't really get it. :(

Comment: some part can easily be moved in the initialisation indeed, but i kept everything in the same block for consistency. But what about the for loop ? what if my initialisation need even more complex code than a for loop ? (eg : populating the array with actual data)

Comment: I sure could create some "init()" method, ensure in my code to call it only once and call it a day. But since there is the possibility to create a static constructor i wanted to give it a try. Found it gave a warning, and now trying to fix it in an elegant way if possible.

Comment: microsofts documentation on CA1810 says there are valid reasons to supress the warning. Granted, you should try to adhere to their suggestions when possible. Aside from that, if your goal is to initialize a variable before it is ever used doing so at declaration is safer and easier to read.

Comment: Hoooooooo i fixed it. For some reason i assumed i got the warning simply because i had a static constructor. But this is not the case !! If i move the initialisation out of the static constructor and only keep the for loop, the warning disappear !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turn out there is a simple way to remove the warning. I assumed the warning existed simply because of the presence of the static constructor, but it is not the case.

While it doesn't strictly answer my question of "how to run code at initialization" it fix the warning :

```
namespace Kerumaton
{
  static internal class WorldGrid
  {
    static public int gridWidth = 10;
    static public int gridHeight = 10;
    static public int gridSizeX = World.imageWidth % gridWidth;
    static public int gridSizeY = World.imageHeight % gridHeight;
    static public int[][] gridArray = new int[gridSizeX][];

    static WorldGrid()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < gridArray.Length; i++)
        {
            gridArray[i] = new int[gridSizeY];
        }
    }
  }
}
```